# Gold badge users have too much power to close questions

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

In this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59922424/unable-to-figure-out-this-basic-python-error-lenvariable-7-is-giving-wrong
gold badge user closed it very quickly for a wrong reason.

It seems like there should be more responsibility for wrongly closed questions? Perhaps more votes needed?

In this particular case, even admitting that reason was completely unrelated, gold badge user did not seem to care. If he didn't understand question, in his opinion that's enough to keep it closed.

I'm not against giving gold badge users such power. But there should be a mechanism to keep them in check, to report if they are doing poor job, and maybe revoke such permission. We have automatic check system for review queues, it could be similar.

Comment: Yep, that's my bad, sorry, but: 1. I made that mistake because the OP did not make it clear what the actual problem was; and 2. *as I said there* there's no point reopening typos. And there *is* a checking mechanism; you can vote to reopen, flag and/or bring it up on meta.

Comment: Note the irony of me closing this with my gold badge.... hmmm

Comment: The gold badges only have power to hammer close duplicates, so it doesn't matter whether or not your question applies to dupes, as the powers of gold badges only applies to dupes.

Comment: Again, this question is not about dupes, not at all. Yet, you closed it as dupe of unrelated questions. I didn't ask about dupes. It's about gold badge users using their power too quickly. It might be true that gold badge can only close dupes, but in these cases it was used too broadly.

Comment: @mvp gold badge users have no more power than any other user when it comes to close voting non-duplicates. So it is relevant. There is no issue - they are just like any other user with close vote privileges. Can you understand that?

Answer (score 11):

You're generalizing from one poor example.

The aim of StackOverflow is to get a repository of questions & answers, not to answer every personally customized question of each user.

This gold badge system allowed to close thousands of questions very quickly in order

- to provide an answer to the new, duplicate question
- to avoid that someone loses time to answer to something that has been already answered

This was a huge success for the site. Of course, sometimes one can abuse their power and close with a bad duplicate but

- you can edit your post and ping them, asking them to reopen
- another gold badge owner can reopen singlehandedly if the question isn't a duplicate after all.
- a gold badge owner can change the duplicate target (or add more duplicates) by editing the list of "original" questions

Note that it's not forbidden to comment so the OP doesn't feel that the closure is so harsh (as discussed in [Should we add more explanation when closing as duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352439/should-we-add-more-explanation-when-closing-as-duplicate))

> It seems like there should be more responsibility for wrongly closed questions? Perhaps more votes needed?

Users who achieved 1000 votes on their answer generally know all the frequently asked questions over and over. They *could* answer it again and get more internet points, but most of the time they prefer linking to a good set of answers for this same/very similar question.

Note that it used to need 5 votes from standard users, now it only needs 3 to close a question, and that works pretty well too, so I would say that relatively, the power of gold badge owners (and moderators) has decreased.

It also means that only 3 non-gold badge owners can *reopen* the question if it's a wrong duplicate.

(okay, enough of the generic blurb :))

---

In that particular case, the user used the "is floating point math broken" generic duplicate. I admit this was too quick and was a mistake, but what harm has this done?

At least noone wasted time answering that one...

It appears that the question is a typo, so it's useless for StackOverflow. The OP realized it and deleted it.

And even if it hadn't been deleted, reopening would have made no sense, since it was going to be closed as a typo.

> I'm not against giving gold badge users such power. But there should be a mechanism to keep them in check, to report if they are doing poor job, and maybe revoke such permission. We have automatic check system for review queues, it could be similar.

We cannot revoke this right for a particular user, unless this user gets so many downvotes that the score in the tag goes below 1000. Nevertheless there *is* a mechanism. It's called *moderation*.

Every gold badge owner has been too quick once in a while, just because they usually want to *avoid* answers on duplicate questions. We have too many of those. So sometimes there's a mishap. Of course there are cases of abuse of the gold badge (closing, preparing answer, reopening to be the first to answer being a famous misuse). If that happens, flag the user for moderation, and if this is becoming an habit for this user, moderators can warn them, and suspend them if this goes too far (that would revoke the user from doing *anything* on the site for a while)

To set things right, you could also have flagged the question for moderation, explaining that the close reason was wrong. A sane moderation action would have been (if the post wasn't deleted) to reopen and close as a typo immediately. It doesn't matter much for that example (no answers, question deleted)

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up a bit. I'm concerned when first time posters get such treatment - it will turn them away from using site altogether

Comment: Alternatively, it may teach them to try to look at their problem in ways they may not have thought of, thus possibly leading them to their answer without having to first ask next time.

Comment: @mvp yes, I think this should be done with a comment directed to the new OP, so OP hasn't the impression that it's closed by a bot